# invalid destination position for blit using class

Tags: python, class, pygame

Anyone know what the problem is here? There is other code but its irrelevant, if you think there's more to the problem just comment and ill post the whole code.

```
class Coin():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xcord = x
        self.ycord = y
        self.coinsprite = pygame.image.load("coin.png")

def main():
    coin = Coin(30, 40)

    screen.blit(coin.coinsprite, ([coin.xcord],[coin.ycord]))

run = True
while run:
    main()
    pygame.display.flip()

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gabriel/PycharmProjects/2d dungeon game/main.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/gabriel/PycharmProjects/2d dungeon game/main.py", line 94, in main
    screen.blit(coin.coinsprite, ([coin.xcord],[coin.ycord]))
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit**
```

Edit: Ive fixed the problem, changed the coin name to c1. Dont know why it worked.

```
class Coin():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xcord = x
        self.ycord = y
        self.coinsprite = pygame.image.load("coin.png")

def main():
    c1 = Coin(30, 40)

    screen.blit(c1.coinsprite, (c1.xcord,c1.ycord))

run = True
while run:
    main()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Forgot to write the square brackets, which turned out to be the problem. No idea why I did it to begin with.

Comment: Please, provide full traceback, not just last line

Comment: @buran oops, sorry. Included full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():
    coin = Coin(30, 40)

    screen.blit(coin.coinsprite, ([coin.xcord],[coin.ycord])) #<- Your problem is here
```

You're passing the coordinates as lists.
Do it like this

```
def main():
    coin = Coin(30, 40)

    screen.blit(coin.coinsprite, (coin.xcord, coin.ycord))
```